# Declaring String and ArrayList problems

Tags: java, android

I have this code.I included a bigger part of it,in case i'm missing something from the other methods that could cause my crash.
I'm delaring as instance variable some Strings and some ArrayLists.The user inputs values into some EditTexts,they go inside an `ArrayList(allpret,allcant,allprod)`.From there i take each value and put it in `Strings(pret,prod,cant)` so i can reference it with `cant[1],pret[1][prod1],etc.`
I must have declared it wrong,don't know how to fix it because it crashes when i try to run `calculeaza()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    TextWatcher {

public Button paginanoua;
public Button produsnou;
public Button Salveaza;

float totaltest = 0;
public int k;
public int j;
public int l;
public TextView totalc;
private static final String TAG = "MEDIA";

public List<EditText> allprod = new ArrayList<EditText>();
public List<EditText> allpret = new ArrayList<EditText>();
public List<EditText> allcant = new ArrayList<EditText>();

String[] cant=new String[allcant.size()];
String[] pret=new String[allpret.size()];
String[] prod=new String[allprod.size()];

public void produsnou() {
    final LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setHint("Produs");
    l1.addView(et);
    allprod.add(et);
    et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if (hasFocus && 
                       l1.getChildAt(l1.getChildCount() - 1) == v) {
                    produsnou();}}
    });

    LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
    et2.setHint("Cantitate");
    et2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

    allcant.add(et2);
    l2.addView(et2);
    et2.addTextChangedListener(this);

    LinearLayout l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
    EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
    et3.setHint("Pret");
    et3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    l3.addView(et3);
    allpret.add(et3);
    et3.addTextChangedListener(this);}



public void calculeaza() {

    totaltest = 0;
    for (int m = 0; m < allprod.size(); m++) {

        prod[m] = allprod.get(m).getText().toString();
        if (prod[m].matches("")) {
        prod[m] = Float.toString(0);}}



    for (int j = 0; j < allcant.size(); j++) {

        cant[j] = allcant.get(j).getText().toString();
        if (cant[j].matches("")) {
            cant[j] = Float.toString(0);}}



    for (int k = 0; k < allpret.size(); k++) {
        pret[k] = allpret.get(k).getText().toString();
        if (pret[k].matches("")) {
            pret[k] = Float.toString(0);}}

    for (int l = 0; l < allpret.size(); l++) {

        Float temp = Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);
        alltotal.add(temp);
        totaltest = totaltest + temp;

        TextView totalf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        totalf.setText(String.format("Total: %.2f", totaltest));}}
```

I get the following LogCat :

> 06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at com.example.testlayout.MainActivity.calculeaza(MainActivity.java:209)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at com.example.testlayout.MainActivity.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:283)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7395)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7454)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9213)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:676)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:435)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:333)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>   06-13 23:03:03.670: E/AndroidRuntime(15089):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Line 209 is this : `prod[m] = allprod.get(m).getText().toString();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variables are initialised before the constructor starts, in their order of appearance:

```
public List<EditText> allprod = new ArrayList<EditText>();
String[] prod=new String[allprod.size()];
```

So when `prod` is initialised, `allprod` is empty and its size is 0. So `prod` is an empty array and you can't place anything in it.

You possibly meant (I have not looked at the details of your code) to use an ArrayList instead, which has a dynamic size.

Comment: I can make calculeaza work,i did that by declaring `String[] prod=new String[allprod.size()];` inside of calculeaza().But then when i want to use for example prod[1] outside calculeaza(in my case put it inside a txt file) it won't find it because it's declared inside calculeaza method.So my question now is,how can i declare it inside calculeaza(as that is what i need to do for it to work) but stil be able to use it outside of calculeaza ?

Comment: @SorinGrecu You can declare it at the same place as in your original code: `String[] prod;`, but initialise it in `calculeaza()`: `prod = new String[allprod.size()];`. Or, just use an `ArrayList` and if you need a `String[]` at some stage, you can call `String[] prodArray = prod.toArray(new String[prod.size()]);`.

Comment: Thanks,i've learned something new thru this mistake,hehe.Still a beginner with no programming background but stackoverflow is helping me a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Your String arrays are zero length as you initialize them with the size of empty lists.
Initialize them after filling you lists. I.e. at the beginning of your `calculeaza` method.

Comment: But if i initialize them inside the calculeaza method,then i won't be able to use cant[1] for example outside that method,right ? I did that and when i try and put cant[1] into a file(txt) it crashes.

Comment: @SorinGrecu you can declare it as a member variable and initialize it there (give it values) then you can access it from anywhere in the Class